# Remove Ubuntu 20.04 from Lubuntu 20.04

Tags: 20.04

```
sudo apt purge ubuntu-desktop -y && sudo apt autoremove -y && sudo apt autoclean
```

Will not work. I get this message:

> Package 'ubuntu-desktop' is not installed, so not removed

What's going on?

Comment: It means that you already ran the command successfully. What leads you to believe that it "*will not work*?"

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. Lubuntu 20.04 LTS does not come with the `ubuntu-desktop` installed, only the base part of Ubuntu (which is included with all *flavors* and Ubuntu Desktop itself, as well as Ubuntu Server). The error message is correct, so what is your issue? or what are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Thanks to both of you for responding. I had Ubuntu 20.04. I installed Lubuntu on top of it without realizing that it already has LXQT desktop environment. Regardless, now I have both Lubuntu and LXQT (they appear separately on my login screen) on top of Ubuntu. When I am inside Lubuntu, I try to get rid of Ubuntu. This is what I see on my login screen: https://postimg.cc/gX3PDw0t I want to get rid of everything except Lubuntu.

Comment: You have no doubt added more than just GNOME (Shell), as LXDE hasn't been part of Lubuntu since 18.04 and isn't supported by Lubuntu on any release past 18.04 so  shouldn't exist on a Lubuntu 20.04 system. You can look at https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/lubuntu-desktop for clues as to what should be there, OR look at your apt logs (`/var/log/apt/history.log`) or command `history` to see what you've added, maybe even a `dpkg -l |grep gnome` (but you'll have to exclude packages that belong there; ~10 packages), but more history would help. Your system looks heavily modified from the picture.

Comment: Trying to remove desktops completely is usually a lot harder than installing them.  Sometimes it is easier to do a clean install, of live with what is left over.

Comment: guiver, i never used a word LXDE. Where do 
 you see that?

Comment: It's the first option listed in your picture; 4 desktops are listed, and the WM on a DM I cannot recognize (ie. heavily modified or even a non-Ubuntu maybe)